# Rails 3 really very very strange behavior flash variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

ruby-1.9.3-p194
Rails 3.0.9

I encountered so much strange behavior of **flash** variable.

**My controller**

```
class AdviceController < ApplicationController
    # POST /advice/save.js
    def save
        t = Logger.new(STDOUT)

        t.debug '+============================================'
        t.debug flash['advice-saving-error-msg']
        t.debug '+============================================'

        flash['advice-saving-error-msg'] = 'strange string'

        t.debug '============================================'
        t.debug flash['advice-saving-error-msg']
        t.debug '============================================'
    end
end
```

When I ask **save** action **first time** I see in debug:

```
+============================================
nil
+============================================
============================================
strange string
============================================
```

When I ask **save** action **next time** I see in debug!!!!!!!!!!!!:

```
+============================================
strange string
+============================================
============================================
strange string
============================================
```

It makes me crazy! Why!!!

I expect to get:

```
+============================================
nil
+============================================
============================================
strange string
============================================
```

It looks like Rails saves flash variable through action call.
Could Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Flash.now`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now). Basic flash saves it for the next action.